# Azure function v3 - Twilio output binding does not work

Tags: azure, twilio, azure-functions

I am trying to create an azure function (v3) on .net Core 3.1 with TwilioSms Output binding. I referred to Microsoft official docs for the same

My function looks like :

```
 [FunctionName("QueueTwilio")]
 public async static Task Run(
        [QueueTrigger("sms-queue", Connection = "AzureWebJobsStorage")] JObject req,
        [TwilioSms(AccountSidSetting = "TwilioAccountSid", AuthTokenSetting = "TwilioAuthToken")] 
         IAsyncCollector<CreateMessageOptions> smsMessages,
        ILogger log)
        {
              var message = new CreateMessageOptions(new PhoneNumber("+14xxxxxxxxx"))
                        {
                            Body = "Hello", 
                            From = "+18xxxxxxxx"
                        };

                        await smsMessages.AddAsync(message);

        }
}
```

I want the method to run asynchronously and a list of messages to fire in one call, hence, using output binding instead of return statement

```
[FunctionName("QueueTwilio")]
 [return: TwilioSms(AccountSidSetting = "TwilioAccountSid", AuthTokenSetting = "TwilioAuthToken", From = "+1425XXXXXXX")]
```

After trying everything, I still get error :

> Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host: Exception binding parameter 'smsMessages'. Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Twilio: Method not found: 'Void Twilio.Clients.TwilioRestClient..ctor(System.String, System.String, System.String, System.String, Twilio.Http.HttpClient)'.

Libraries used :

> Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Twilio 3.0.0 ; 
>   Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions 3.0.3

Comment: maybe a better place you'd be open an issue on the official Github repo.

Comment: It's been more than a year and a half, so this may not be relevant to you anymore.
Anyways, it would be great to get the full source code to debug this issue. 
Without the source code I'm shooting in the dark, but maybe the wrong namespace is used for `CreateMessageOptions`? There are 3 different namespaces with the `CreateMessageOptions` type, it should be `Twilio.Rest.Api.V2010.Account`.
Anyways, I'm writing an article about Twilio + Azure Functions which I'll post here when it's done. Maybe it'll help you and others running into this issue.

Comment: NVM, looks like you submitted a GH issue and found your answer: https://github.com/Azure/Azure-Functions/issues/1612